# OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS ported to OpenGL on Mac OS X rendering models inside out

Tags: macos, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on a multi platform game. It uses OpenGL ES 2.0 and the whole scene renders perfectly fine on iOS and also windows using Mali's OpenGL ES emulator.

I recently ported it to Mac OSX. The only change I had to make was to get glCompileShader to ignore lowp, mediump and highp. Other than that, for the most everything seems to work fine with the exception of all models rendering inside out.

I've tried the following to fix it without any luck..

Disabling culling altogether
Switching cull mode between front, back, front and back
Switching front face to be CW and CCW

Enabling, disabling depth buffer
Trying less, greater, lequal and gequal for depthfunc
Reversing near and far in the projection matrix

The only other thing I could think of is the handedness. My scene is authored in a left handed coordinate system. I end up flip the z axis of the view matrix to compensate for it. So, on OSX, I tried flipping back the view matrix and trying LH and RH projection matrix combinations with that and the results behaved as expected with the exception of models rendering inside out.

At this point I'm totally stumped.

It seems like some default state is different between OpenGL ES an OpenGL.
Ideas?

Comment: Weird. Normally code should carry over smoothly as long as you use a common subset of functionality. Does it look like everything is transformed to the wrong position on the screen? Or only the front and back flipped? Or are things in the right place, but only the depth test is not working correctly?

Comment: Well, everything is kind of a wild guess, but I figure you verified that you actually have a depth buffer?

Comment: You were right, the sample code I used to setup my open gl context forgot to initialize the depth buffer.That was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. I did not have a valid depth buffer. For some reason, the sample code I used to setup my OpenGL context forgot about the depth buffer.

Thanks to Reto Koradi for pointing it out.